# react router only update url

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

When I click the profile navigator the url change but the page doesn't. I try to move the router tag into index.js, using withRouter in my App.js and Profile.js but it's not work. I already use exact inside my url for homepage. This the code App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route path="/profile" component={withRouter(ProfilePage)} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And this is Home.js

```
const home = () => {
    return(
        <Router>
            <div className="container">
                <img src={environment} alt="environment" className="environment"/>
                <Link to="/email"><img src={pos} alt="pos" className="pos"/></Link>
                <Link to="/profile" className="profile"><img src={profile} alt="profil"/></Link>
                <Link to="/experiences"><img src={experience} alt="experience" className="experience"/></Link> 
                <Link to="/projects"><img src={project} alt="project" className="project"/></Link>
            </div>
      </Router>
    );
}
```

Profile.js

```
const Profile = () => {
    return(
        <div className="profile-container">
            <h2>Profile</h2>
            <span className="line"></span>
            <img src={photo} alt="photo-profile" className="photo-profile"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Update Home page and remove Router page:

```
const home = () => {
return(
        <div className="container">
            <img src={environment} alt="environment" className="environment"/>
            <Link to="/email"><img src={pos} alt="pos" className="pos"/></Link>
            <Link to="/profile" className="profile"><img src={profile} alt="profil"/></Link>
            <Link to="/experiences"><img src={experience} alt="experience" className="experience"/></Link> 
            <Link to="/projects"><img src={project} alt="project" className="project"/></Link>
        </div>
);
```

}

I think this the problem you try to call Router twice.